# How copy logs in chef-handler to workstation?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I try to copy logs to workstation from nodes.

I am new in chef and ruby.

In recipe:

```
directory "/var/chef/handlers" do
recursive true
action :nothing
end.run_action(:create)

cookbook_file "/var/chef/handlers/chef_handler_hibu.rb" do
action :nothing
end.run_action(:create)

chef_handler "Chef::Handler::Copy" do
source "/var/chef/handlers/chef_handler_hibu" 
end.run_action(:enable)
```

In files

```
class Copy < Chef::Handler
def initialize

end
def report
execute "report" do
command "sshpass -p ******* scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /var/log 
/#{node["ipaddress"]}.log gestchef@192.168.107.214:/var/log/chef_clients_logs
/#{node["ipaddress"]}.log"
end
end
end
```

But the execute method is undefined in chef handler.

How can I execute a linux command in a chef Handler?

Or How can do this with ruby?

I try this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'


class Copy < Chef::Handler
def initialize

end
Net::SSH.start("192.168.107.214", "*****",:password => "******") do |session|
session.scp.download! "/var/log/#{node["ipaddress"]}.log", "/var/log
/chef_clients_logs   /#{node["ipaddress"]}.log"
end

end
```

But error

```
cannot load such file -- net/scp

gem list --local

net-scp (1.0.2)
net-sftp (2.0.2)
net-ssh (2.0.11)
s3sync (1.2.5)
xml-simple (1.0.12)
```

And

```
gem which net-scp
Can't find ruby library file or shared library net-scp
```

What happened?

Answer (score 3):

After much searching, and many tests, this is what has worked for me.

In recipe:

```rb
    directory "/var/chef/handlers" do
      recursive true
      action :nothing
    end.run_action(:create)

    cookbook_file "/var/chef/handlers/chef_handler_hibu.rb" do
      action :nothing
    end.run_action(:create)

    chef_handler "Chef::Handler::Copy" do
      source "/var/chef/handlers/chef_handler_hibu" 
    end.run_action(:enable)
```

In `files/default/chef_handler_hibu.rb`:

```rb
    class Copy < Chef::Handler

      def report

        mpadd = Chef::Resource::Execute.new(mpadd,run_context)
        mpadd.command("sshpass -p ***** scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /var/log
    /#{node["ipaddress"]}.log gestchef@192.168.107.214:/var/log/chef_clients_logs
    /#{node["ipaddress"]}.log")
        mpadd.run_action(:run)
      end
    end
```

With this, you can copy logs of nodes to anywhere, in the `chef_handler` stage.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: +1 for sharing this, I got hint from here to solve my issue too..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753546/copy-file-from-chef-client-node-to-workstation/18753980#18753980..