# Copying zip file from remote machine to a remote machine using chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to copy a zip file of whose path i want to give in my source attribute of **remote_file** or **cookbook_file**  resource. But when i give the path it gives an error 
**IPADDR:PORT/xyz/abc/a.txt" is not a valid `source` parameter for remote_file. `source` must be an absolute URI or an array of URIs** .
I wanted to know is there a way to give username and password along with the source???
I achieved this by keeping the file at the apache's root folder **/var/www/** and then used the https protocol
but i wish to achieve this when i have a file located at any location.

Comment: have you tried including the protocol?  https or http?

Comment: Yes i did that, that was how i came accross the solution of keeping in apache's root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a remote file using chef resource `remote_file`, that file have to be accessible from the local machine with a valid URI. Knowing whis, I think you have two possible implementations:

1. Share the file with the protocol you wish. You can use http (using a web server); you can use ftp, you can use nfs, you can use samba... Most of these sharing protocols let the authentication, so you can control the access to the file.
2. Yo can copy the file using scp. There is a clever implementation of this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753546/copy-file-from-chef-client-node-to-workstation). If you want to avoid having the sensible information in your recipe, I would recommend manage that information using encrypted databags.

Comment: Going with the second approach, i will need to write a recipe which will be firing scp commands on the remote machine.
I will try it out

Comment: Thanks for your second approach. SCP is working, i just gave the keys among the machines and without password it is working.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, the `remote_file` resource is for downloading remote content *over HTTP*, not SSH or anything else.