# Need chef recipe to migrate file between machines

Tags: copy, chef-infra

I am struggling to get chef recipe to copy/transfer file from one server to another with standard way of communication like scp. I did't get proper reference yet.

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753546/copy-file-from-chef-client-node-to-workstation) one is not working for me

Comment: I would suggest to implement that using [Net::SCP](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp) instead of via call to the `scp` executable.

Comment: Remote file resource supports both http and ftp. See; https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html Unfortunately not scp :-(

Comment: I done this myself and working well, still I will verify with Net::SCP. Thanks for the reply guys.